# Center rectangle in ScrollPane's ViewPort

Tags: java, javafx-8

My `ImageView` has specific areas that need to be shown when selecting specific filters (i.e. show objects of color X).

The form is structured like this: `ScrollPane` -> `Group` -> `ImageView`.

**Zooming works**, but I can't find a way to reliably center the view and show the whole area containing the filtered objects (`Rectangle2D`)

```java
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Group main;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imgView;

    @FXML
    public void onMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        switch (event.getButton()) {
            case PRIMARY:
                CalculateRectangle();
                break;
            case SECONDARY:
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(event.getX() - 50, event.getY() - 50, 100, 100);
                rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                main.getChildren().add(rect);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void CalculateRectangle() {
        ArrayList<Double> xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
        xMin = new ArrayList<>();
        xMax = new ArrayList<>();
        yMin = new ArrayList<>();
        yMax = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node node : main.getChildren()) {
            if (!node.equals(imgView)) {
                xMin.add(node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX());
                xMax.add(node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
                yMin.add(node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());
                yMax.add(node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY());
            }
        }
        if (!xMin.isEmpty() && !xMax.isEmpty() && !yMin.isEmpty() && !yMax.isEmpty()) {
            double xmin = Collections.min(xMin),
                    xmax = Collections.max(xMax),
                    ymin = Collections.min(yMin),
                    ymax = Collections.max(yMax),
                    width = xmax - xmin,
                    height = ymax - ymin;
            ensureVisible(new Rectangle2D(xmin, ymin, width, height));
        }
    }

    private void ensureVisible(Rectangle2D rect) {
        double widthView = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
        double heightView = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        double sx = widthView / rect.getWidth();
        double sy = heightView / rect.getHeight();
        double scaleFactor = Math.min(sx, sy) * 0.80;//ensure there's enough space for the rectangle + some margin
        main.getTransforms().setAll(new Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor));
        /********************************************************************************************/
        /**//*this results in (xMin,yMin) being visible while the rest depends on form size and zoom*/
        /**/scrollPane.setHvalue(rect.getMinX());
        /**/scrollPane.setVvalue(rect.getMinY());
        /********************************************************************************************/
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        scrollPane.setVmax(imgView.getImage().getHeight());
        scrollPane.setHmax(imgView.getImage().getWidth());
    }
}
```

Scene.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" onKeyTyped="#onKeyPressed" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="stackoverflow.FXMLController">
    <content>
        <Group fx:id="main">
            <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="imgView" onMouseClicked="#onMouseClicked">
                    <viewport>
                        <Rectangle2D height="500.0" width="1000.0" />
                    </viewport>
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../image.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </children>
        </Group>
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: There is nothing to correct, I simply don't have enough knowledge of javafx to figure this out. Setting any value of scrollpane changes its position relative to the view.Setting HValue(x) and VVAlue(y) means only that point is always shown, because the point won't be at (0,0) of the viewport, meaning my rectangle will be shown only partially

Comment: sigh ... always the same story, since decades ... The easier you make it for potential helpers the quicker you'll get an answer. You are a programmer, aren't you? So you **know** that having a piece of _runnable_ code and play with it is **lots** easier than talk about code ..

Comment: The structure of the layout is also importtant. Post the fxml content.

Comment: There you go gentlemen. (Image.png is a blank 2000*600 image)